# Set of matrices that commute with $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Which are matrices $2\times 2$ that commute with the matrix
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\1&1\end{array}\right]?$$

Comment: If you multiply that matrix by a generic $2 \times 2$, you get four simultaneous equations. Have you tried solving them?

Answer (score 4):

Work explicitly to get
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a+b&a+b\\c+d&c+d\end{pmatrix},$$
and
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a+c&b+d\\a+c&b+d\end{pmatrix}.$$

Can you finish it from there?